# Trying to view citations in Bibtex as an import file from Mendely isn't working

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

but wanting to try and write my thesis using this. I am using TexMaker as the editing software.  All my references thus far have been in Mendeley and i have exported this into LaTex.  I am now trying to cite a specific reference which has been cited as Zumla2016 in mendeley but when i write 
`\cite{Zumla2016}`

The output is `[?]`

I don't know why but i guess it is not reading the citation. I am completely new to all this but the total preamble in exported bibliography for this reference is this:

```
@article{Zumla2016,
author = {Zumla, Alimuddin and Rao, Martin and Wallis, Robert S and Kaufmann, Stefan H E and Rustomjee, Roxana and Mwaba, Peter and Vilaplana, Cris and Yeboah-Manu, Dorothy and Chakaya, Jeremiah and Ippolito, Giuseppe and Azhar, Esam and Hoelscher, Michael and Maeurer, Markus},
doi = {10.1016/S1473-3099(16)00078-5},
issn = {14733099},
journal = {The Lancet Infectious Diseases},
month = {apr},
number = {4},
pages = {e47--e63},
title = {{Host-directed therapies for infectious diseases: current status, recent progress, and future prospects}},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S1473309916000785},
volume = {16},
year = {2016}
}
```

Must i write all this every time?

Thank you and sorry for being clueless!

Vani

Comment: Just to add - adding the above preamble just creates more question marks.  So nothing seems to be able to recognise the reference.

Comment: Do you have a `\bibliographystyle` instruction in your tex file? Do you have a `\bibliography` instruction in your tex file? Did you run BibTeX after running LaTeX, followed by two more LaTeX runs?

Comment: Hi! I have typed \bibliographystyle{style} in my tex file. How do you mean by running Bibtex and latex again?  I did try and press bibtex on the latex file but it's not doing much other then putting more info in the preamble box. It's probably not helping by the fact I am not able to save the document at the moment either.

Comment: Well, do you also have a `\bibliography` instruction, likely towards the end of your tex file?

Comment: No! I guess I should?  There is a separate .bib file. but do I need to write something at the end of the edited tex file?  Is this why I can't save it at the moment also?

Comment: Incidentally, is your bibliography style file really called `style[.bst]`?

Answer (score 0):

Some comments and suggestions, in no particular order.

- Mendeley is a tool to help assemble a `.bib` file. It's important to realize that Mendeley does not, and will not, create a formatted bibliography. All it does it to help create the bib file(s).
- Creating the formatted bibliography for a LaTeX document is the job of BibTeX (or `biblatex`). BibTeX needs to be made aware of three key inputs:

  - The file that contains the raw bib inputs. This file must have filename extension `.bib`. The instruction `\bibliography` should contain, in its argument, a list of one or more bib filenames, *without* the `.bib` extension.
  - Information about which formatting guidelines should be applied to the bib entries as well as to the citation call-outs. This information should be in the argument of a single `\bibliographystyle` instruction. Bibliography style files must have exension `.bst`.
  - Which entries from the bib file(s) should actually be extracted and formatted? That's the job of the `\cite` commands.
- Judging from your description, you have so far provided neither `\bibliography` nor `\bibliographystyle` instructions. You probably haven't run BibTeX either, right?
- Assuming appropriate `\bibliography` and `\bibliographystyle` instructions have been provided and assuming that various `\cite` instructions are present in the tex file, and assuming the tex file is called `myfile.tex`, the compilation sequence should be

  ```
  latex myfile
  bibtex myfile
  latex myfile
  latex myfile
  ```

  Depending on your editing software, there may be a drop-down menu from which to choose latex and bibtex runs.

---

Here's the output of a full MWE (minimum working example). It uses the `plainnat` bibliography style and the `natbib` citation management package. The bib entry is contained in a file called `mybib.bib`. Incidentally, there is an error in your bib entry: the argument of the `month` field should be either `apr` or `{April}`, but not `{apr}`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{Zumla2016,
author  = {Zumla, Alimuddin and Rao, Martin and Wallis, Robert S. and Kaufmann, Stefan H. E. and Rustomjee, Roxana and Mwaba, Peter and Vilaplana, Cris and Yeboah-Manu, Dorothy and Chakaya, Jeremiah and Ippolito, Giuseppe and Azhar, Esam and Hoelscher, Michael and Maeurer, Markus},
doi     = {10.1016/S1473-3099(16)00078-5},
issn    = {14733099},
journal = {The Lancet Infectious Diseases},
month   = apr,
number  = {4},
pages   = {E47--E63},
title   = {Host-directed therapies for infectious diseases: Current status, recent progress, and future prospects},
url     = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S1473309916000785},
volume  = {16},
year    = {2016}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}  % just for this example
\begin{document}
\cite{Zumla2016}
\bibliography{mybib} % place the formatted bibliography *here*
\end{document}
```